# Glycolytic non-oxidative pathway

Tags: metabolism, energy, physiology

I am currently digging in some books to understand the three major metabolic pathways involved in physical training. The most difficult one for me is the glycolytic non-oxidative pathway (also more commonly known as the anaerobic lactic pathway) and I would like some help from people versed in this field.

In this pathway, as far as I understand, glycolysis produces pyruvate. In this process, NADH and H+ ions are produced along the way.

Then, if there is still a high energy demand (i.e. glycolysis is still necessary); NADH binds with pyruvate to form lactate and free up NAD+ which is necessary to sustain the glycolysis (otherwhise, pyruvate would be consumed via an oxidative pathway i.e. oxidative glycosis or slow glycolysis). This can theoretically continue until glycogen is depleted or severely diminished as far as I understand.

The problem comes then from the H+ ions produced during the glycolysis. These ions cause acidosis of the muscles if not removed. However, they can be removed if sufficient oxygen is present to form water. **And here is my main question :**

Why, during high intensity exercise, would oxygen be insufficient to take care of the H+ ions produced by the glycolysis ? Is it because muscles used during high intensity are not the best ones for using/transporting oxygen? Is it also because these H+ ions cannot be transported towards neighbouring muscles able to oxidise H+ ions ?

I understand this is a difficult question and maybe there is no precise answer at the moment. If you could point me toward a good ressource that deals with this question, I would be glad. I currently base myself on McArdle book on exercise physiology.

Comment: This is a great question, but not really on topic for fitness. I am migrating it to biology, where it may get a higher level of attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to try to walk through this problem, in a step-by-step manner in relation to exercise, starting from at rest, and ending at the point in which the body is no longer able to maintain its energy-charge.

### At Rest

The body mainly utilises oxidative phosphorylation to maintain its energy-demands. In cells where great amounts of energy need to be produced very quickly, *eg.* [cells that are actively replicating](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19460998), glycolysis is the preferred mode of energy production because this pathway is able to very quickly produce large amounts of ATP, and lactate is able to quickly diffuse in to the bloodstream. Lactate will travel in the bloodstream, to the liver, to be recycled back to glucose through an anabolic process called gluconeogenesis. This recycling pathway is known as the *Cori-cycle*. Essentially, what is happening is, parts of the body that are in need of high amounts of energy, will "dump" their wastes to the bloodstream, to be dealt with by other organs.

[Science and Skiing VI, 2015, pp 17-30](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=eugMBgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA17&dq=lactic+acid+recycling+during+exercise&ots=ZySGozX_Bf&sig=LF0aToo_i0NpIZYLkf4D-MED-0o#v=onepage&q&f=false). George Brooks of the University of California summarises lactate recycling quite nicely here.

### Beginning Exercise

Muscle cells will begin to quickly utilise ATP-stores, and release glucose from the glycogen-stores, and release oxygen-stores from myoglobin.

As these stores begin to become depleted, the body will begin to go in to overdrive, in an attempt to restore itself to a resting-state. Thus, your heart-rate will increase, breathing will become faster, and glycolytic pathways will be activated through feed-forward mechanisms.

### During Exercise

[I have touched on this before, in another post that you may find interesting.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60232/how-does-heart-beat-faster-while-doing-a-strenuous-task/60268#60268) I believe that if you read through this though, that you will understand why there is low levels of oxygen, and what the body does to attempt to circumvent this.

There will be very low levels of oxygen throughout the active tissues. The body will do everything it can to try to restore this, but it will ultimately fail to do so. Thus, the only real option it has is to rely on glycolysis in the tissues that are causing "problems". [The rate of ATP-production is most dependent on the rate at which a cell can take glucose in to the cell](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2880972/).

The electron-transport-chain is only able to synthesise ATP at its *maximum velocity* - this maximum velocity is proportional to the concentration of oxygen. The rate of glycolysis is, however, essentially, only affected by the rate at which lactate can be removed from the cell and the rate at which glucose can be absorbed by the cell.

Of course, the muscles that are being used will only be concerned with producing energy. Therefore, all of the lactate that they produce will be dumped in to the bloodstream, where it will travel to the liver, in the previously mentioned *cori cycle*.

---

Overall, the issue is not in the muscle-cell's ability to regenerate NAD+. This is the easy part, seeing as there is no net-change in the concentration of NAD+ when glucose is converted to lactic acid. And also, things such as *malate-aspartate shuttles*, *citrate-pyruvate shuttles*, and *glycerol 3-Phosphate shuttles* can be used to maintain redox-balance. These are only but a few examples of how to maintain redox-balance.

You must also remember that carbohydrates are not the only class of molecules involved in these cycles; degraded proteins and fats can also be used to supply the TCA-cycle with alternative means of energy-production. Pyruvate probably would not even be able to be converted in to acetyl-CoA anyway, since [pyruvate dehydrogenase requires the presence of oxygen to function](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep31146).

Problems however do arise once the body is unable to deal with all of the waste that it is producing. There will reach a point, where the liver cells will be physically incapable of accepting any new lactate-molecules. And so, lactate will accumulate in the bloodstream. With an accumulation of lactate in the bloodstream, lactate will be unable to diffuse to the outside of the cell. Thus, cells will be unable to convert pyruvate in to lactate.

The reason why ATP-regeneration eventually fails to keep up with the rate of ATP-usage, is because the rate of conversion to lactate decreases. The rate of conversion to lactate decreases, because the concentration of lactate increases

I tried to make a little illustration of what I mean above, below. Hope this helps to conceptualize it.

[image]

In this second picture, there is too much lactate for diffusion to occur.
[image]

**Supporting information**

Taken from [Quantifying intracellular rates of glycolytic and oxidative ATP production and consumption using extracellular flux measurements](http://www.jbc.org/content/292/17/7189.full); Mookerjee et al. 2017

"These maximum values of JATPglyc and JATPox define the bioenergetic capacity of the cells. As shown in Fig. 5D, the maximum individual capacities of JATPglyc and JATPox in the bioenergetic space plot intersect at (62.5, 46.5) for a theoretical maximum bioenergetic capacity of 62.5 + 46.5 = 109.0 pmol of ATP/min/μg of protein. At this maximum point, the glycolytic index (GImax capacity) would be 62.5/109 = 57.3%, making C2C12 myoblasts primarily glycolytic when running at their maximum ATP production rate. Compared with the actual value of JATP production in the presence of glucose (55.2), the bioenergetic capacity was 109/55.2 = 197% of the rate with glucose (Fig. 5D). This bioenergetic capacity of 197% of the rate with glucose (alternatively, a reserve capacity of 109.0 − 55.2 = 53.8 pmol of ATP/min/μg of protein) reveals that the C2C12 cells under our experimental assay conditions with added glucose were operating comfortably within their capacity to generate ATP and were well set up to respond to any acute increases in ATP demand by increasing either glycolytic or oxidative ATP production, or both."

In these experiments, the researchers were trying to figure out what proportion of ATP would be created by glycolytic and oxidative pathways in muscle cells (and other cell-types). Their findings, were that, indeed, the majority of ATP production in muscle cells comes from glycolysis.

During exercise, this difference in amounts of ATP production between glycolysis and oxidative phosphorylation would probably be even greater.

Comment: I noticed that someone does not like this answer. If you could provide feedback on how to improve this or tell me why I am wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Bob - I did not downvote you.  However this is incorrect (not completely so please don't take offense -- just missing some key factors). @xusr is on the right track. Will add on in a sec

Comment: True. However, it is not really about the amount of ATP that can be produced. It is about how quickly that ATP can be produced. By using glycolysis, the cell will be able to produce a greater amount of ATP than it would be able to if it were trying to cycle through the entire TCA-cycle & ETC. Also, the TCA/ETC does not shut down.. Not at all; it will however utilize alternative substrates, such as amino acids or fatty acids. The amino acids and fatty acids will be present in sufficient amounts to fuel the TCA relative to the amounts of oxygen that is present. And, as I said, when a cell is

Comment: using glycolysis to produce lactic acid. This lactic acid will be dumped in to the bloodstream to be processed by different organs - mainly the liver. Cancer cells use a similar mechanism - for those of you who have studied cancer, you know this.. Cancer cells *do not* use oxidative phosphorylation, because they can grow much more quickly by relying on glycolysis, and allowing the rest of the body to deal with the lactic acid.

Comment: @Mike-DHSc , Yes please do add on. I'm interested to see what you think.

Comment: @Bob Yes exactly where I was going -- I'm not a chemistry guy - I'm a PT so you'll run laps around me in that area.  You actually hit most areas (and some I didn't even pick up on the first time around) - was trying to find an excerpt from a book that explains it well but no luck.

Comment: I'm posting 2 images now -- maybe you can make better sense of them then me.

Comment: @Mike-DHSc Great! I'll take a look. But, which part was the part that you thought was incorrect? I'd like to look in to that a bit more also.

Comment: One sec I'll add them shortly

Comment: From What I understand (I am an engineer, not a chemist), I'll tag along with Bob. What I understand is, during intense exercise, your body is doing whatever it can to maintain its balance. So oxidative processes (using fat mainly I guess) are running at 100% (VO2max) but are not sufficient to produce ATP quickly enough (the ATP production rate is not enough to compensate ATP use rate). So non-oxidative processes such as ATP-PC (quickly depleted) and non-oxidative glycolysis enter the game. Oxidative glycolysis is not able to proceed because

Comment: non-oxidative is more efficient in terms of ATP production rate (not in terms of ATP yield per glucose molecule) and the body favours this one in view of the energy demand

Comment: @FenryrMKIII No, it would mainly use glucose, not as much fat. And, "efficiency" is relative to whichever state the body is currently in. While at rest, oxidative phosphorylation is more than enough to maintain appropriate ATP-levels, **and** you get ~36ATP per glucose molecule, so in resting cells this is much more efficient because it also allows preservation of resources. I don't really think you can say any one pathway is "more efficient".. Cells will always try to react in such a way that is optimal to a given situation - and if burning through the bodies glucose-stores to produce lactate

Comment: happens to be the optimal option during exercise, that is what the cell will do. To think of certain processes as being the "most efficient" leads people to believe things like "the paradox to anaerobic energy production during exercise". So yes, you are right on the money with: "your body doing whatever it can to maintain its balance".

Comment: Let's forget the word efficient. Rather, non-oxidative glycolysis is the pathway that is able to provide ATP at a sufficient rate so that ATP stores are replenished sufficiently fast compared to their use. Now one thing I don't understand from your answer is how can the body use glucose with oxidative processes while under intense activity ? Since in such situation, according to my understanding, glucose is needed for the non-oxidative glycolysis and oxidative glycolysis being the only other pathway to use glucose,

Comment: it is not possible for the body to perform oxidative glycolysis while non-oxidative is underway

Comment: @FenryrMKIII "Non-oxidative glycolysis ... provides ATP at a sufficient rate", correct! And, I do not think that the body would use very much glucose for oxidative phosphorylation - since the enzyme (PDH) that converts glucose in to AcCoa will not be active due to the low levels of oxygen. Instead, I think the TCA cycle would more so be powered by amino acids and fat (although minimal amounts of glucose might still get theough).

Comment: To my understanding, conversion of glucose to AcCoa is not active because the body knows (I don't know how exactly) that he needs to sustain non-oxidative glycolysis (not because oxygen levels are low, oxygen is in fact very present to my understanding given the intense activity). If he goes the AcCoa way, then pyruvate is used and no lactate is formed. Therefore, NAD+ is not replenished to fuel glycolysis and it stops and there is an ATP production hole. In the end I think we agree: during intense activity, non-oxidative glycolysis and oxidation of fat and amino acids provide the ATP.

Comment: Well, oxygen is "busy" being the terminal electron acceptor of the electron transport chain (ETC) - which is fueled by NADH/FADH2 produced by the TCA cycle.. But yeah, close enough!  As you can see, it's a very complicated question you have asked.

Comment: That is why I asked it :) Because in the books I have, the way they explain it is not clear enough and they contradict themselves sometimes.

Comment: No! The oxygen levels **have** decreased, IIRC the pO2 (in the blood tissue, at least) *can* drop down by something like 50torr - which is enough of a pressure drop to inactivate PDH - that's what causes the preference of glucose towards glycolysis. But, yeah, oxygen is definitely still there - just not as much of it, so the TCA/ETC *will* still work, just not as well as it was working prior to exercise.. Everything else that you said after "If he goes the AcCoa way, then pyruvate..." I agree with.

Comment: Can you please stop excessive commenting and discuss over in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere)?

Comment: **pyruvate dehydrogenase requires oxygen as a cofactor to function** No, it does not. In biochemistry a cofactor is a non-protein component of an enzyme's active site. The linked paper explores the way in which hypoxia influences the regulation of PDH through phosphorylation.

Comment: @AlanBoyd Good catch, thanks. Better?

Comment: Thanks @xusr, but I'm going to have to ask you to kindly start reading *more* carefully, *ie.* stop skimming through. Because, no where did I ever say that O2 is consumed/produced in the TCA. And also, you don't need to become Alan's echo - we already noted the whole phosphorylation thing at least three hours before your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic question!  Hopefully this somewhat helps.  It's very difficult to simply this process as it's quite complex.

During high intensity exercise, energy demands exceed either:

1. The O2 supply
2. The rate of use exceeds the at which it becomes available.

So the respiratory chain cannot process all of the H+ joined to NADH.

Continued release of anaerobic energy during glycolysis depends on NAD+'s availability to oxidize 3-phosphoglyceraldehyde -- otherwise glycolysis grinds to a halt.

[image]

During anaerobic glycolysis -- NAD+ "frees up" when excess hydrogen's combine temporarily with pyruvate to form lactate.  **Lactate formation requires one additional step catalyzed by lactate dehydrogenase.**

[image]

The storage of H+ with pyruvate represents a temporary "collector" of the end product of anaerobic glycolysis.  Once lactate is formed it diffuses away into the interstitial space and blood for buffering and removal.

However, this avenue for energy is temporary.  Blood lactate and muscle lactate levels increase and ATP regeneration fails to keep pace with the rate of use.  Fatigue sets in and performance diminishes.

---

**EDIT**

- H+ = a free electron
- Increasing the concentration of free H+ ions = lowers the pH (so a pH
  of 1 is very acidic and has a very high concentration of free H+
  ions, a PH of say 9 has a lower concentration of H+ ions and is less
  acidic).
- Oxidation is losing electrons – reduction is gaining electrons.
- During glycolysis NADH is oxidized.  The regeneration of NAD+ (this
  is the reduced form of NADH)  during the reduction of pyruvate to
  lactate is required for glycolysis to continue under anaerobic
  conditions.
- Several key steps in the oxidation of glucose to pyruvate involve the
  reduction of the electron/energy shuttle NAD+ to NADH. It's required
  to reoxidize the NADH to NAD+ in order to avoid consuming the
  available pools of NAD+ and to thus avoid stopping glycolysis.
- Put differently, during glycolysis, cells can generate large amounts
  of NADH and slowly exhaust their supplies of NAD+. If glycolysis is
  to continue, the cell must find a way to regenerate NAD+, either by
  synthesis or by some form of recycling.

  Let me know if that helps!

---

### UPDATE

So these slides will have to do for now (best I have available to post).  Put very simply in anaerobic conditions - there comes a point where there is not enough NAD+ available to convert pyruvate to lactate.

Would H+ ions just accumulate and increase local acidosis?

### [image: Update]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So lactate production allows capturing h+. Then why is there acidosis during non-oxidative glycolysis? Not all h+ are captured? Also you say there is either lack of oxygen use (I can understand that if muscles are  not well trained to process oxygen or if they are fast twitch which possess less mitochondria for oxidative processes) or lack of supply. How can there be lack of supply during high intensity? Is this because the oxidative pathways are already at 100% and use all the available oxygen? Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I edited my post.  Hopefully that helps

Comment: Two errors in the edit: H+ is not an electron; NAD+ is the oxidised form; there is only one step in glycolysis where NADH is generated.

Comment: @Bob Well, obviously, but that isn't what the sentence *Several key steps in the oxidation of glucose to pyruvate involve the reduction of the electron/energy shuttle NAD+ to NADH.* conveys, at least to me.

Comment: Okay. So, have you heard of alternative splicing? Basically, different organs/tissues *can* have proteins that perform the same function, but the efficiency at which the proteins function will vary. So, in your first picture there, it is showing that the LDH-protein in the heart is less likely to use glycolysis to produce lactate - since, because the heart is quiet vital to life, damage to this organ needs to be minimised. In your second picture there, it is showing that pyruvate will not be converted to acetyl-coenzyme A in the absence of oxygen - which is required by pyruvate dehydrogenase.

Comment: I disagree though with: "there comes a point where there is not enough NAD+ available to convert pyruvate to lactate." this should not be a problem - because of the reasons I listed in my answer. The problem arises when there is a build up of lactate - because the equilibrium will not allow any further shift from pyruvate. So, basically, yeah - "H+ ions just accumulate and increase local acidosis", although it isn't actually the problem.. the problem is the presence of lactate. "H+" does not actually exist as a free ion.

Comment: "This avenue for energy is temporary because blood lactate and muscle lactate levels increase and ATP regeneration fails to keep pace with the rate of use. Fatigue sets in and performance diminishes.

Anaerobic Conditions mediate fatigue by inactivating various enzymes in energy transfer and impairing the muscles contractile properties."  I'm reading otherwise...

Comment: @Mike-DHSc Yes, but this has nothing to do with the concentration of NAD+. Remember, each time you convert glucose to lactic acid, there is no net-change in the concentration of NAD+. The reason why ATP-regeneration eventually fails to keep up with the rate of ATP-usage, is because the rate of conversion to lactate decreases. The rate of conversion to lactate decreases, because the concentration of lactate increases.

Comment: @Bob ah I see -- you seem to have a very strong understanding exactly what's going on.  What you've outlined matches what I'm reading.  I put too much stock in NAD+ Regeneration being some type of rate limiting step.  You're correct - thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for more references to add to my answer. I probably should have done this in the beginning, because I do realise that this particular topic seems to contradict a lot of the things that classic biologists take to be gospel. If you find anything interesting, I would like to read it also. One of the references that I am reading right now claims that glucose - uptake is one of the main limiting step in the initial stages of switching to mostly glycolysis. I'll post it once I think I've found a sufficient amount of supporting information.

Comment: A cited detailed explanation would definitely be helpful.  I primarily read rehab / health / fitness studies articles etc.-- for work and fun.  If something in that realm comes up I'll let you know.

Wish they had a member reviewed medical based forum on this site to answer questions and add that type of information.